# Sorting list dict by index and get top n elements

Tags: python

What I have is a list of dict:

```
x = [{25: 16}, {40: 32}, {11: 50}]
```

What i am trying is to sort it by value and get the top n elements:

where `n = 2`

what i did:

```
sorted_lst = x.sort(key=lambda d: d.values)
print(sorted_lst)
filtered = sorted_lst[:n]
```

but this did not work.

the output that I am trying to get is:

```
[{11: 50}, {40: 32}]
```

Comment: you meant to use `sorted`?

Comment: tried with that as well `sorted_lst = sorted(x, key=x.get)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: `sorted(x, key = lambda i: next(i.values().__iter__()), reverse = True)[:2]`

Comment: @deeenes that is in asc order, I needed it in desc order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: The linked question is not about a list of dictionaries. This questions has a different solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without iterator in lambda

```
x = [{25: 16}, {40: 32}, {11: 50}]
sorted(x, key = lambda i: list(i.values()), reverse = True)[:2]
>>> [{11: 50}, {40: 32}]
```

Comment: Is it better without iter?   like sorted(x, key = lambda x: next(iter(x.values())), reverse=True)[:2]

Comment: For me it is more readable and i don't have to know what `next(iter(...))`does. But I like your solution, too. Perhaps post as answer and let the voting system decide?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly different solution to @mikksu's variant, using `iter` and `next`.  `Iter` turns the view of values into an iterator and `next` gets the first value.

```
sorted(x, key = lambda x: next(iter(x.values())), reverse=True)[:2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`collections.Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to get the top n elements:

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = [{25: 16}, {40: 32}, {11: 50}]
>>> [{k: v} for k, v in Counter(dict(tuple(*d.items()) for d in lst)).most_common(2)]
[{11: 50}, {40: 32}]
```